# Is it acceptable to include non-step methods in step definition classes?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cucumber, specflow, gherkin

Commonly, one tries to keep step definition classes as simple as possible and offload most of the business logic into object models. As a rule of thumb, we try limit the methods in step definition classes to binding step definition methods.

However, in some cases, multiple step definitions use similar code. One approach would be to extract this code in a new method within the same step definition class. For example:

```
[When(".....")]
public void WhenX() {
   // Do custom logic
   commonMethod():
}

[When(".....")] 
public void WhenY() {
   // Do custom logic
   commonMethod():
}

public void commonMethod() {
   // Common code
}
```

Another approach would be to move this code to a helper class. However, seeing as this code is only used within a single class, it might make more sense to bind it's scope to the respective class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is acceptable. We can keep non step definitions in the same class. It wouldn't cause any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Steps classes are just plain old java classes so you can do whatever you need in them.

I would probably not have a public method in my step definition class. I would declare it private. If it should be used from other steps, I would write it in another class and use it in the step definition class. The benefit of doing that is that it gets easier to share common functionality between steps.

Extracting logic like this can be seen as the first step towards creating a helper layer between the steps and the system under test, i.e. your production code.

Using a helper layer, and thus keeping your steps as one or two liners, are considered a good practice.